# Integers, Float and Beautiful Soup Attribute

Tags: python, int, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get my all_data tags into a format where I can do a comparison with them with a Boolean. I think it involves using the float and/or an int operator. However, I have some concerns as the output once the site is scrapped. The output is in integers, decimals and percentages. The specific line I am talking about modifying is line 33. I have tried using int() and .int. I haven't found any questions on Stackoverflow about this or in Beautiful Soup documentation.

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import re
import urllib
import urllib2
from urllib2 import HTTPError
# import modules

symbolfile = open("symbols.txt")
symbolslist = symbolfile.read()
newsymbolslist = symbolslist.split("\n")

i = 0

f = csv.writer(open("pe_ratio.csv","wb"))
# short cut to write

f.writerow(["Name","PE","Revenue % Quarterly","ROA% YOY","Operating Cashflow","Debt to Equity"])
#first write row statement

# define name_company as the following
while i<len(newsymbolslist):
    try:
        page = urllib2.urlopen("http://finance.yahoo.com/q/ks?s="+newsymbolslist[i] +"%20Key%20Statistics").read()
    except urllib2.HTTPError:
        continue
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
    name_company = soup.findAll("div", {"class" : "title"}) 
    for name in name_company: #add multiple iterations?        
        all_data = soup.findAll('td', "yfnc_tabledata1")
        stock_name = name.find('h2').string #find company's name in name_company with h2 tag
        try:    
            f.writerow([stock_name, all_data[2].getText(),all_data[17].getText(),all_data[13].getText(), all_data[29].getText(),all_data[26].getText()]) #write down PE data
        except (IndexError, HTTPError) as e:
            pass
    i+=1
```

This is what the output looks like in the CSV file.

```
Agilent Technologies Inc. (A)   25.7    -2.80%  5.60%   N/A 51.03
```

Please keep in mind you load the stock ticker symbols by putting them in vertically in the symbols.txt file.

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert your all_data string values to numbers try something like this:

```
all_data = soup.findAll('td', "yfnc_tabledata1")
stock_name = name.find('h2').string #find company's name in name_company with h2 tag

clean_data = list()
for x in [data.GetText().strip(' %') for data in all_data]
    try: 
        clean_data.append(float(x))
    except ValueError:
        clean_data.append(x)

try:    
    f.writerow([stock_name, clean_data[2], clean_data[17], clean_data[13], clean_data[29], clean_data[26]]) #write down PE data
except (IndexError, HTTPError) as e:
        pass
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run comparisons on the data (i.e. is quarterly percent greater than 25) you'll have to format the text so it can be converted to a number

```
quarterly_percent = all_data[17].getText()
if quarterly_percent != "N/A":
    #cut off the percent sign and conver to a "python number"
    quarterly_percent = float(quarterly_percent[:-1])
    if quarterly_percent > 25:
        print "its a good one"
```